# Update two lists update by timestamp linq for Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core

Given two lists of the following type, one in my database (backed by EF Core), and another list fetched from a web service:

```
public class Data
{
    public string Ticker { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime Updated { get; set; }
}
```

I have the following:

```
async Task SaveTickersToDatabaseAsync(IEnumerable<TickerV2> webData)
{
    using var scope = AsyncScopedLifestyle.BeginScope(this.container);            
    using var context = container.GetInstance<TickersDbContext>();

    try
    {
        var dbData = context.Tickers.Select( x => x);
            
        var toInsert = webData.Except(dbData);

        var toDelete = dbData.Where(c => !webData.Any(d => c.Ticker == d.Ticker)).ToList();
            
        var toUpdate = dbData
                        .Join(webData, db => db.Ticker, web => web.Ticker, (db, web) => new { Db = db, Web = web })
                        .Where(joined => joined.Web.Updated > joined.Db.Updated)
                        .Select(x => x.Web)
                        .ToList();

        context.AddRange(toInsert);
        context.RemoveRange(toDelete);
        context.UpdateRange(toUpdate);
        
        await context.SaveChangesAsync();

    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        this.logger.LogError(e, e.Message);
    }
}
```

And then write to Entity Framework Core.

Please how can I get the list `toUpdate`, based on the `Ticker` matching, but `Updated` time from the web service data being newer than what is the database list - would this be the correct way about doing this "upsert"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understand correctly, you search the query :

```
var toUpdate = fromWebService
    .Where(c => fromDatabase.Any(d => c.Ticker == d.Ticker && c.Updated > d.Updated))
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Hi Sajid, thanks for the reply, yes that makes sense - just realized can add some further context with relation to Entity Framework